# Is this function $f$ defined at the origin?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$f(x,y,z)=\ln{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$$

Is the function defined at the origin?

If so, what is its value and if not, give the reason.

Comment: Do you know what it means to be 'defined at the origin'? Did you try computing $f(0, 0, 0)$? What was your result, and what issues did you run into?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: i exactly dnt knw plz explain it to me 'defined at the origin'

Comment: @ash That would be important information to include in your question. Your question isn't really "is it defined," it's "what does the phrase mean."

Answer (score 2):

One may recall that
$$
\ln :(0,\infty)\mapsto \mathbb{R}
$$ and
$$
\sqrt{ 0^2+0^2+0^2}=0
$$ the given function is **not defined** at $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$.